# Getting exception when trying to get nested Json API Objects C#

Tags: c#, json, api, http, object

So right now I am working on a C# console app, and I am trying to send HTTP requests to an API endpoint and only getting specific data from that endpoint back. I am not having issues with sending the request, but am having issues trying to get specific objects from the Json API.

Here is the code I have written for getting data from the API request

```
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        string responseData = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        dynamic jo = JObject.Parse(responseData);
                        var jsonData = jo["channels"]["client-events"]["states"]["state"].ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine(jsonData);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[Here is what the API endpoint itself looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M9bP.png)

I am trying to get the "state" object which is the child of "states". But when running the code I get this exception
"System.ArgumentException: 'Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "state". Int32 array index expected."

Which seems to be an issue with the "state" object itself.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io/ - five minutes there solves 99.9% of JSON problems. Many people will come here and tell you how to make your code work. But don't be fooled. Try quicktype. ;)

Comment: Can you show the value of `responseData`

Comment: In general, it would be useful if you pasted the JSON as text in your question.  In order to replicate the problem one often needs to copy both code and JSON, and it is not possible to do this from an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is that the 'states' property is an array and you need to specify the array index and then get the 'state' property value from it

```
var jsonData = jo["channels"]["client-events"]["states"][0]["state"].ToString();
```